# What my dog really hears

Tags: code-golf, string, substitution

My dog is called Rex. Every time I scold him, he seems not very impressed and the only times I see him react is when I pronounce his name. If I say

`Rex, I told you not to do this! You're making me angry Rex!`

all he hears is

`Rex, * **** *** *** ** ** ****! ***'** ****** ** ***** Rex!`

**The challenge** : given an input string, your program must output the same string where all alphabetic characters have been turned to stars, except the characters in the appearances of the word `Rex`, who must be left untouched. The non-alphabetic characters are also left untouched.

**Details** : The challenge is case-insensitive, thus `rex` must be left untouched also. The word `Rex` can be part of another word, so for example `anorexic` must be rendered as `***rex**`.

**Update** : as the initial text of this challenge did not clarify how underscores or numbers or accentuated characters should be treated, I do not make any special requirement on those characters. Thus, a solution is valid as long as characters in `a-zA-Z` (and also the one mentioned in the examples, `,!".`) are handled correctly.

Test cases :

Input : `Rex lives in Rexland.`

Output : `Rex ***** ** Rex****.`

Input : `To call Rex, just say "Rex".`

Output : `** **** Rex, **** *** "Rex".`

Input : `My cat is getting anorexic.`

Output : `** *** ** ******* ***rex**.`

Comment: Will the string contain newlines?

Comment: Test case: `Hello! Isn't this ... a nice challenge?` Can you dog hear `*****! ***'* *** ... * **** *********?`? If so, you might consider communicating in morse from now on...

Comment: Do we only need to support `a-zA-Z`, or also `0-9` and/or `äëïöüÿãõñáéíóúýàèìòùç` etc. etc.? And could you add some test cases regarding these?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Since $0-9$ or accented characters are not mentioned in the initial challenge, do not consider them as part of the challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy I think we can assume standard ASCII, but replace digits or not is a good question.

Comment: @Shaggy *The non-alphabetic characters are also left untouched.* Alphabetic characters don't include digits.

Comment: Can I have an additional new line character at the end?

Comment: Will there be newlines in the middle of the string?

Comment: Since ["dogs don't get the difference between lowercase and uppercase"](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119718/what-my-dog-really-hears#comment293292_119718), may the output case be different to the input? (For example: input=`"Rex lives in Rexland."`, output=`"rex ***** ** rex****."`; or alternatively input=`"My cat is getting anorexic."`, output=`"** *** ** ******* ***Rex**."`)

Comment: I once had a dog that could spell.

Comment: @Joshua Really ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Yeah really. We're pretty sure it came from spelling words we didn't want him to overhear. Near the end we were pretty sure he could spell any word he knew, which was quite a few.

Comment: Does Rex not respond to [Dog park, walk, treat]? When my dog was shaking I made a joke about him having "Dog parkinsons"  and he definitely only heard "Dog park******"

Comment: @Adám Indeed. Sorry for the mistake, I just corrected it

Comment: @EwanDelanoy You may want to wait more than two days before accepting an answer, for two reasons: Challenges with no accepted submission may be less attractive, and you are likely to have to reaccept (which could cause bad feelings). I generally wait a week or so, except if there is a 0-2 byte solution.

Comment: @Adám Thanks you for your advice. I don't have much experience for participating in this forum. At least my motives for reaccepting are crystal clear (number of bytes).

Comment: Ewan, we still need an answer to @Adám's [question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119718/what-my-dog-really-hears/119742#comment293673_119718) about underscores.

Comment: @Adám Yes, I wasn't sure about the best way to fix the challenge and had forgotten about my earlier comment. Hope it's all OK now

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Yes, thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @Adám & Ewan; that [saves me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119742/58974) 3 bytes :)

Comment: Why did this challenge use asterisks [instead of "blah"s???](http://static.tumblr.com/yptklcp/FEVl6nors/blahblah_header.jpg)

Comment: Idea possibly from [Far Side](https://desertdemocrat.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/gary-larson-far-side-cartoon-what-we-say-to-dogs-blah-blah-ginger.jpeg).

Comment: [This answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119734/43319) is shorter than my accepted one.

Comment: [My new answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/128596/43319) is shorter than the newly accepted one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

```
i`(rex)|(\w)
$1$#2$**
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/ifmaBRlFqhWaMRU67JpWKoomykoqX1/39QaoVCTmZZarFCZp4CkJOTmJeixxWSr5CcmJMDEtBRyCotLlEoTqxUUAJylfS4fCuBkiUKmcUK6aklJZl56QqJeflAszOT9QA)

#### Explanation

Skipping `rex`s is easiest by matching them as well, because matches can't overlap. So if we give priority to `rex` over other letters, those will be covered in a single match and not touched by the individual-letter matches.

But how do we do different things depending on the alternative that was used for the match? Unfortunately, Retina doesn't (yet) have any conditional substitution syntax like the Boost regex flavour. But we can fake it by including both substitutions in a single replacement and making sure that only one of them is non-empty:

- `$1` is the first capturing group, i.e. the `(rex)`. If we did match `rex` this simply writes it back (so it does nothing), but if we didn't match `rex` then `$1` is an empty string and vanishes.
- `$#2$**` should be read as `($#2)$*(*)`. `$#2` is the number of times group `2` was used, i.e. the `(\w)`. If we matched `rex` this is `0`, but if we matched any other individual letter, this is `1`. `$*` repeats the next character as many times as its left-hand operand. So this part inserts a single `*` for individual-letter matches and nothing at all for `rex`.

Comment: Doesn't retina have `\a` for `[a-z]` z.B.?

Comment: @LeakyNun no. I'd have to tokenise the regex (or even implement my own flavour) to add any features to the regex flavour itself.

Answer (score 164):

### **REXX <s>151</s> <s>148</s> 141 bytes **

(Kinda seemed appropriate)

```
i=arg(1)
m=i
o=translate(m,'',xrange('A','z'),'*')
p=0
do forever
   p=pos('REX',m,p+1)
   if p=0 then leave
   o=overlay(substr(i,p,3),o,p)
end
say o
```

[Try it here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_rexx_online.php)

Notes for non-REXXers:

1. translate is a character replacement function (name comes from an assembler instruction on IBM MF).  It searches string1 for the characters in string3. Every time it finds one it replaces it with the same positioned one in string2. If string2 is too short it is padded with the pad character.

[See here for translate function](http://www.rexxinfo.org/html/functions.html#translate)

2. overlay simply overlays the string1 on top of string2 at the specified position.

[See here for overlay function](http://www.rexxinfo.org/html/functions.html#overlay)

Comment: ... but the dog thought he programmed it in REX*.

Comment: How many of these upvotes are purely for the choice of language?! :D

Comment: @Shaggy At least all of them

Answer (score 24):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>42</s> <s>41</s> 38 bytes

```js
s=>s.replace(/rex|\w/gi,m=>m[1]?m:"*")
```

---

### Try It

```js
o.innerText=(f=

s=>s.replace(/rex|\w/gi,m=>m[1]?m:"*")

)(i.value="Rex, I told you not to do this! You're making me angry Rex!")
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)
```

```html
<input id=i><pre id=o>
```

---

### Explanation

```js
s=>            :Anonymous function that takes the string as an argument via parameter s.
s.replace(x,y) :Replace x in s with y.
/rex|\w/gi     :Case-insenstive regular expression that globally matches all occurrences
                of "rex" or any single letter, number or underscore.
                (numbers & underscores will never be included in the input.)
m=>            :Anonymous function that takes each match as an argument via parameter m.
m[1]?          :If string m has a second character, ...
                (Equivalent to m.charAt(1))
m              :Return m, ...
:"*"           :Otherwise return "*".
```

Comment: See https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119718/what-my-dog-really-hears/119746#comment293303_119718

Comment: nice solution!.

Answer (score 13):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
'rex' '\w'⎕R'\0' '*'⍠1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#PY4xDoJAEEV7T/GhmcQYorfQwobYmNBMYIOry27CDspewE5jY@/ZuAguJlK@/Df/z7hV3A73F7WqJ1Bxo@H5zqlYR1jS8PhsxnFSQLnqV9hBnKkQXAfrJAIqBzlpn@DoOootaPiibY1GgW3dBsS7hBZzB4y@Kg9tp8CwrbJ/eHAo2Rj8hs6dF3gOSCOms7MP0RFoj1qJTDtsXXxdlxl9AQ)

Simple PCRE **R**eplace.

`⍠1` sets case insensitivity. Simply replaces `rex` with itself and all other word characters with asterisks.

Comment: `\w` includes the underscore character, assuming this is RegEx - I don't know APL.

Comment: @Shaggy Yeah, Dyalog APL uses PCRE, but it is not certain from OP that underscores will occur. E.g. digits will not.

Comment: Do we not have to assume they can occur, unless told otherwise?

Comment: @Shaggy Normally, yes, but [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119718/what-my-dog-really-hears/119746?noredirect=1#comment293303_119718) seems to indicate that what isn't mentioned will not occur. OP only mentions comma, period, space, and exclamation point.

Comment: Hmm ... I think I'll wait for confirmation that they *won't* occur, seeing as I've left that comment about `\w` on a few answers now!

Answer (score 11):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 24 bytes

23 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

I used Martin Ender's regex from his [Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119734/55508) (which happens to be shorter in Perl, thanks to `\pl`), and only had to adapt the right side of the s///.

```perl
s%(rex)|\pl%$1//"*"%gie
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#U1YsSC3KUdAt@F@sqlGUWqFZE1OQo6piqK@vpKWkmp6Z@v9/UGqFQnJiiUJmsUJ6aklJZl66QmJePlBtZrIeAA)

Answer (score 8):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```
iS`(rex)
%iT`Ll`*`^(?!rex).*
¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/ifGZygUZRaocmlmhmS4JOToJUQp2GvCBLR0@I6tI3r//@g1AqFnMyy1GKFzDwFICcnMS9FjyskXyE5MScHJKCjkFVaXKJQnFipoATkKulx@VYCJUsUMosV0lNLSjLz0hUS8/KBZmYm6wEA) Explanation: Splits the string into occurrences of the word `rex` and everything else, but keeps the matches. Then, on lines that don't begin `rex` (i.e. the "everything else"), change letters to `*`s. Finally, join everything back together.

Comment: This is at least the second time that I'm thinking transliteration mode could use an option to transliterate the non-matches...

Comment: @MartinEnder too late :-D

Answer (score 8):

### C, <s>99</s> <s>97</s> <s>92</s> <s>86</s> <s>74</s> <s>73</s> <s>72</s> 65 bytes

```
f(char*s){*s&&f(s+=strnicmp("Rex",s,3)?!isalpha(*s)||(*s=42):3);}
```

Pelles IDE environment provides (compile with /Go) the function strnicmp. This function is identical to strncasecmp. See it [work here](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#jZBNbsIwEIX3nOI1C2STqEXQbppGPUE3VXcBVVbigKvgRBkHQUPOntoWLSD1bxaj8Ty/z@MZCpatRTMh3k1oPC4YhQmZRmeCZLapWfAsd0FE0Zw/XikSZb0WzF4@HGxObmf8fs7jflDaYCOUZthWKgcfdSPYcGTkwoh0mc7upksk6OCVH6KDew@l2kqC0rCHUuj8OkCP6A/jS4VMlKXzRHhryYDEHgsHXAT/IjztLcFAEVbSGKVXELpq5E5lv9t7xF7yya3Cffk1q1pbJiD1LquC@SY4bi4aqV0KP7cXVcM8Q@ncbiLBFPGxfjjnHpthaJftx/8a7pPs9RPdRd0a@l7tTxOM@uED) (with the replacement function).

The output is stored in the first parameter which is an in/out parameter.

Thanks to [Johan du Toit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/johan-du-toit) for letting me know that recursion is slightly shorter.

Comment: There exists a C environment that provided strncmpi so you can get it in 69. I've got it on CD.

Comment: @Joshua Thanks. What is CD?

Comment: Borland C++ 4.5

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, <s>36</s> <s>35</s> 32 bytes

```
->s{s.gsub(/(rex)|\w/i){$1||?*}}
```

As a test:

```
f=->s{s.gsub(/(rex)|\w/i){$1||?*}}

tests = [
  ["Rex, I told you not to do this! You're making me angry Rex!", "Rex, * **** *** *** ** ** ****! ***'** ****** ** ***** Rex!"],
  ["Rex lives in Rexland.", "Rex ***** ** Rex****."],
  ["To call Rex, just say \"Rex\".", %q(** **** Rex, **** *** "Rex".)],
  ["My cat is getting anorexic.", "** *** ** ******* ***rex**."]
] 

tests.each do |input, output|
  if f.call(input) == output
    puts "Fine for #{input.inspect}"
  else
    puts "Problem with :\n#{input.inspect}"
    puts f.call(input)
    puts output
  end
  puts
end
```

It outputs:

```
Fine for "Rex, I told you not to do this! You're making me angry Rex!"

Fine for "Rex lives in Rexland."

Fine for "To call Rex, just say \"Rex\"."

Fine for "My cat is getting anorexic."
```

Answer (score 6):

## PHP, 78 Bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace("#[a-df-qs-wyz]|r(?!ex)|(?<!r)e|e(?!x)|(?<!re)x#i","*",$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#NY9BT4NAEIXv/Ipha8JigD8AysH00IOamF5M2zQbmMLqdhdnFwVF/zouNR7fvHlf3ivKru0CJDJ0JOwMOakb/rM@PjxuN3frOA9OhlBULd@xJxwS2IAzqobR9KCN8wJqA66VNoRn00eEcBavngFnBKEbGsHHQpYESxyUfEcLUi9HJXSdeSPaGqiEUnDhv/TWgRUjLP8si3zwfvS@A2mhQbf082BfapBVxg7CXglqdPxV3s5FedMRNssQJSrkbLUTaX1K32z6MX4eJuJliEM88bIIKcYJvf6XGA8ryRJ2zZI/YD5j1Rq213vN8u/5Fw)

## PHP, 84 Bytes

```php
<?=preg_replace_callback("#(rex)|\pL#i",function($t){return$t[1]?$t[1]:"*";},$argn);
```

-1 Byte `\w` instead `\pl` in this case underscore and numbers are replaced too

`\pL` is shorter as `[a-z]` or `[[:alpha:]]`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#JY9Na8MwDIbv@RWqG0gyQmDXpVsOo4fCPmD0MpoSPEdNvLp2kJ3R0G1/PbO7i0Dvx4O0qoZ@iJDIUEM4GHJSd@nvunl53W4e11kZHQwhF326Y294zmEDzqgWJjOCNs4v0BpwvbQLeDdjQggnfvQMOCFw3dEEvrZgeRTqoOQXWpA6iIrrtvBGsjUguFJw5X@O1oHlE4Q8KxJffJ6870Ba6NCF@zzYH3WWomB7bmNOnc4u1cO8qu4Hwi48orjAJlA/uDimbJn6fPZdD09LyfLDqIWTRqexyy6EbiQdu93tvrrOO3bDyp/8H1vOKHrDal1rL85/)

Comment: You can use `\w` instead of `\pL`.

Comment: @Adám Thank you it makes my longer approach only 1 Byte shorter and not really clearer what should make in case of underscore or number

Comment: The input will never have any underscores or numbers..

Comment: @Adám I have make an extra point for it and have edit the longer approach why I have found an other improvement

Answer (score 5):

## C (GCC on POSIX), <s>167</s> <s>118</s> <s>93</s> 87 bytes

```c
i,j;f(char*s){for(i=0;j=s[i];i++)strncasecmp("Rex",s+i,3)?s[i]=isalpha(j)?42:j:(i+=2);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#LY7NCsIwEIRfZfGU2LT4dzIEn8CLeBMPS0x1Q0xLNxZF@uyxLd5mdoZvJ5Pyuhb2gd2S5bduOkFmpb3hC101FYXk1EWL7OyzFYuTey8UF6S28jA1DDGG9oHCy8Nus/d7QYXZSD3kJ1IUVvVyRi97PbO1LctyrcdHor/Yq9TtK/FfDkPOIx8C9Y6BIowmYLxV@dyAxRCmgwL/4gSMH5jHVPn4GcMExHB3KVG8A8amc2@y1Q8)

Comment: `f(char*s){for(;*s;s++)strncasecmp("Rex",s,3)?putchar(isalpha(*s)?42:*s):write(1,s-2,3,s+=2);}`. What kind of sorcery is `f(s)char*s;{}`? I've never seen this syntax before.

Comment: Oh, it used to have another parameter but i forgot to remove that.

Comment: Doesn't work correctly, because only the first call to the function works. See here: https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#jVHLTsMwELznK0Y52SSCKsClIeoXcEHc0ghZebQbpU4UO1VLlG8PtlVokaCwB2t3xzO7Hs8U1nHF8q3obxQfq7ZncZ2olLKYgoAr3ctcqDLfdcx/KQ9@qAIK7/nK3khIiabbClbz1UO0rJeMgiTi8TST1NgJkgz7lgpwb/Rgwk5BIbRIszR6XGRIMMIhv8QIOxQN7UsFkjBFI2Rx62NC@AfxtUUumsZyQtSD0lDiiLUVXPv/Ung@GgUNUtiUWpPcQMi2Lw@UX6dPiB3kDmuFffJb3g4mTaDovWwr5prguPvWSI0p/JJuP8RpkCyMEwkWiE/506XuqRkExmy3/tdyn8oOP6vb6Aatfkan8wbeNH8A Solutions in function form, such as this one, must be able to be called again and produce correct results.

Comment: @2501 thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 5):

## Java 8, <s>187</s> <s>192</s> <s>168</s> <s>164</s> <s>159</s> 138 bytes

```java
s->{for(int i=0;i<s.length();System.out.print(s.regionMatches(0<1,i,"rex",0,3)?s.substring(i,i+=3):s.replaceAll("\\w","*").charAt(i++)));}
```

-28 bytes thanks to @OlivierGrégoire.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jZAxb8IwEIV3fsXJk12MRcXWQCt@AAylW9PBNSYcNU6UcygI5benlzRTp0r2cLbed@@9k73YWVn5eNp/dS5YIthYjPcJAMbk64N1Hrb9CHApcQ9O7lKNsQBSGb@2fPlQsgkdbCHCCjqaPd8PZS2ZALiaZ7gkE3ws0lGqbHej5M@mbJKpGJQkmdoXWMaNTe7oSc6Xjxq1qP1V6LleqBcy1HzSsFWixulqoZ56URXY3DoEKfL8W2jxIJRxR1uvk8TpVCmVtV02YXdV8xnY3WhyiHHmkGOS9w@w6jdhNE6KV3@FgBdP3ADwEGzcGzGkBfjrPkQ5/gzatxKcDaGXaTg1lIDsDfKemYv/QjY3hnBzBIVPqe/axpLrQDcS2knb/QA)

```java
s->{                         // Method with String parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=0;i<s.length();  //  Loop over the characters of the input-String
    System.out.print         //   Print:
     s.regionMatches(1>0,i,"rex",0,3)? 
                             //    If we've found "rex" (case-insensitive):
      s.substring(i,i+=3)    //     Print this REX-word (case-sensitive)
     :                       //    Else:
      s.replaceAll("\\w","*").charAt(i++));
                             //     Print the current character,
                             //     or '*' if it's an alpha-numeric character
```

Comment: @Shaggy Should be fixed now. This was posted before it was specified in the comments that `0-9` and accented characters shouldn't be included, only `a-zA-Z` should.

Comment: Could you replace `"[a-zA-z]"` with `/[a-z]/i`?

Comment: @Shaggy Yes/no. Java uses a slightly different regex syntax than python or C# for example. So yes, it is possible to use a case-insensitive regex, but it will be one byte longer: `"[a-zA-Z]"` -> `"(?i)[a-z]"`.

Comment: I think you should use `s.regionMatches(0<1,i,"rex",0,3)` instead of `s.toLowerCase().substring(i,i+(i>l-3?1:3)).equals("rex")`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Take the current code that you have (at 168 bytes), remove the variable `l` and save 4 bytes.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2 or 3, <s>75</s> <s>73</s> 70 bytes

```py
import re;f=lambda s:re.sub('(?i)(rex)|\w',lambda x:x.group(1)or'*',s)
```

Basically the same as my Ruby's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119718/what-my-dog-really-hears/119755#119755).

-2 bytes thanks to @Wondercricket.

As a test:

```py
tests = [
  ["Rex, I told you not to do this! You're making me angry Rex!", "Rex, * **** *** *** ** ** ****! ***'** ****** ** ***** Rex!"],
  ["Rex lives in Rexland.", "Rex ***** ** Rex****."],
  ["To call Rex, just say \"Rex\".", "** **** Rex, **** *** \"Rex\"."],
  ["My cat is getting anorexic.", "** *** ** ******* ***rex**."]
]


for test_in, test_out in tests:
    print(test_in)
    print(f(test_in))
    print(f(test_in) == test_out)
```

Comment: You could save 2 bytes by removing the spacing between `x.group(1) or '*'`

Comment: @Wondercricket: Thank you very much, it's my first golf answer in Python.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 2, 87 Bytes

```py
import re
print re.sub(r'(?i)[a-df-qs-wyz]|r(?!ex)|(?<!r)e|e(?!x)|(?<!re)x','*',input())
```

I guess that can be shortened? :)

Comment: You can get rid of the spaces after the commas between arguments for 2 bytes off.

Answer (score 4):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <strike>37</strike> 33 bytes

36 bytes sourcecode + 1 byte for -r flag.

```
s:(rex)|\w:\1*:Ig
s:(rex)\*:\1:Ig
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/sed#LY7BCsIwEETv@YqxF7VowWv/oAcv4kXoJbShRtOsJFttwG83bsXLwHvLDpNjvQlm3r7bV90eyroZ1N@0pQjhnE9m3qEBk@uRaIInFkBP4KuNK1xoWgeDUd@tHzAaaD@EBHlbKQk4@zQR1i/Gad9X6kzotHP4Nd@myIg6oRAsKnVMcmTYiMEwL5XakyyyXfWhB1vyMe/DFw)

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You use use `.` instead of `\*`

Answer (score 4):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), <s>11</s> 10 + 1 = 11 bytes

+1 byte for the `i` flag.

```apl
rex
\w
&
*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY6xDsIwEEP3fIXbASSE8h8MLIgFieXUROUgzYnkAs3Xh5TF0rNly@9CLrWW/GruX7Mzh9Yufj3iBJXgUKUginaAE@iD84CblH3yWOjFccbiQXFOFb02mC4I/PEZHDcnUHTWXAUThYD/8rNkRaaKseNozbn2UMEZs1fdJilK/8OTbfwD)

Explanation: Case-insensitively replace `rex` and word-chars with itself and asterisks, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>54</s> <s>50</s> 49 bytes

*Golfed 5 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder*

```
i(`[\w-[rex]]
*
(?<!r)e|e(?!x)|r(?!ex)|(?<!re)x
*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#HY7BCsIwEETv@YqpILai/QKhR/HgRbyIFhrapUbTBJJUE/Df67aXHeYts7Pr/NhMKm/uj@/@7ijWtdiKvDpkrqAf5VUWi59jIdYFUxHFdpouFHc4IVjdIdkRxgY26CzCU/kMNztuHGGQb2V6DARpepfAsUzwgFYf8lBmJlqarkTHlKK4WrRSaywFr9EHeJmwYrsqxTnxMkB59BTCfFkay1@rtvwD)

Comment: @Emigna Just realised that my solution does not work for `dex`, it gives `*e*` while yours gives `**x`.

Comment: If you group both stages by putting `(` after the first `i` you don't need to configure the second stage.

Comment: And your first regex can be written as `[a-z-[rex]]`.

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks, this is the first time I'm seeing character classes where you can exclude certain characters

Comment: they exist in several flavours but I believe .NET's syntax for them is unique.

Answer (score 3):

## Gema, 25 characters

```
/[rR][eE][xX]/=$0
<L1>=\*
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '/[rR][eE][xX]/=$0;<L1>=\*' <<< "Rex, I told you not to do this! You're making me angry Rex!
Rex lives in Rexland.
To call Rex, just say \"Rex\".
My cat is getting anorexic."
Rex, * **** *** *** ** ** ****! ***'** ****** ** ***** Rex!
Rex ***** ** Rex****.
** **** Rex, **** *** "Rex".
** *** ** ******* ***rex**.
```

Painful fact that could be `\CRex=$0;<L1>=\*`, but unfortunately `$0` contains the template, not the match. ☹

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, 60 bytes

```
{$args|%{$_-replace'(rex)|\p{L}','$1*'-replace'(x)\*','$1'}}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#RY/BCsIwEETvfsVYoqulCn6AHyDoRbwIhRLbUKNpIkkqLW2/vaa9eFpmHjs7yx7HsWPclq5fdSzbWfFRPBe0saLZ9umnOw@UEDvE9EfNNo1nk4ZhjK6iSXCCN6pAa2po44NAYeCf0i1xNzVZgYq/pS5RCXBd2hZhbRklCwoTSn6Fg9STqbgu9hTAzSDnSmHOf9XOw/EW07lo5pc2cA/pUArvp2yuTWgt8z2FX9bsAZYN4w8)

Comment: My fault. I've replace `\w` to `\p{L}`.

Comment: Interesting idea. Note that using `$args` as an array has consequences when things are quoted, as in one example. And if you're only using the first argument anyway, you don't need the `foreach`.

Comment: @AndreiOdegov You can go back to `\w`. Side note: Are the braces in `\p{L}` really needed?

Comment: very nice Regex, `"$args"-replace'(rex)|\p{L}','$1*'-replace'(x)\*','$1'` is much shorter overall, wrapping `$args` in quotes turns it all into a single string and saves you a lot.

Comment: @Adám The curly braces in .NET  is required.

Comment: @ConnorLSW Thanks for the valuable pointing.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>93</s> 92 bytes

```python
f=lambda s:s and("rex"==s[:3].lower()and s[:3]+f(s[3:])or("*"+s)[s[0].isalpha()<1]+f(s[1:]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Jc1BCsMgEEDRqwyuZhqQhuykHqEnEBc20VSwGhwh7emttNvPg9@DTu712BywYnB5Q1H9W2jNRi1WpnL6ijQ6/MIUkM2iLJWK4iImJsPmamVkl46nQ7rNfzMPQ/2oMTcIKO4fWF2DyLD71mLex6qMUVyloP4F)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 24 bytes

```
42y3Y2mFGk'rex'Xf!3:q+((
```

The input is a string enclosed in single quotes.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29iVGkcaZTr5p6tXpRaoR6RpmhsVaitofH/v3pQaoVCTmZZarFCZp4CkJOTmJeipxCSr5CcmJMDEtBRyCotLlEoTqxUUAJylfQUfCuBkiUKmcUKfv4hCumpJSWZeekKiXn5QLMzk/XUAQ)

#### Explanation

Consider input `'Rex lives in Rexland.'`

```
42    % Push 42 (ASCII for '*')
      % STACK: 42
y     % Implicit input. Duplicate from below
      % STACK: 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 42, 'Rex lives in Rexland.'
3Y2   % Push string 'ABC...YZabc...yz'
      % STACK: 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 42, 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 'ABC...YZabc...yz'
m     % Ismember
      % STACK: 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 42, [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
F     % Push false
      % STACK: 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 42, [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0], 0
Gk    % Push input lower-cased
      % STACK: 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 42, [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0], 0, 'rex lives in rexland'
'rex' % Push this string
      % STACK: 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 42, [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0], 0, 'rex lives in rexland', 'rex'
Xf!   % Strfind and transpose: gives indices of matchings as a column vector
      % STACK: 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 42, [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0], 0, [1; 14]
3:q   % Push [0 1 2]
      % STACK: 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 42, [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0], 0, [1; 14], [0 1 2]
+     % Addition, element-wise with broadcast
      % STACK: 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 42, [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0], 0, [1 2 3; 14 15 16]
(     % Assignment indexing: sets indicated entries to 0
      % STACK: 'Rex lives in Rexland.', 42, [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0]
(     % Assignment indexing: sets indicated entries to 42 (that is, '*'). Implicit display
      % 'Rex ***** ** Rex****.'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 128 bytes

```bash
r=REXrex;a=`tr -c $r'",. !
' l<<<$1`;for i in {r,R}{e,E}{x,X};{
a=`echo ${a[@]//$i/$(tr $r f-k<<<$i)}`;}
tr $r l<<<$a|tr f-l $r*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#JYxBC4IwGIbv/orXGFgxk84qdOnQ1VMRgUNXjnSDrwXG2s/ubLOO7/PyPBOV1f5IcsxFWVtC2oBRsuAbxFGCvigKtq3zqyEoKA1HvPJO8r13Iz/63EVBk01nwJw47y5ZxlTGliHECNf0Pvtq5evcR3/2K4q3nd8@gPU0TZUcOQ6wpm/xMk9oY8NAa2A79YhxMs@EJAZxV/qGQULoG70QtPijTdqIppNf)

I'm sticking to tr on my previous answer, non-functional bash array string replace and no preg replace!

Less golfed:

```bash
    a=`echo $1 |tr -c 'REXrex.,\"! ' 'z'`;        -> a replaces with z chars in input not matching REXrex or punctuation
    for i in {r,R}{e,E}{x,X}; {                   -> iterates over rex .. rEx .. REX
      j=$(tr 'REXrex' 'ABCabc' <<<$i)}            -> holds a for r, A for R, ando so on
      a=`echo ${a[@]//$i/$j`;                     -> replace each combination of rex .. rEx .. REX with abc ... aBc.. ABC
    }
    tr 'REXrex' 'z' <<<$a |tr 'ABCabcz' 'REXrex*' -> replaces each remainig r,e,x,R,E,X with z and finally each ABC with REX and z with *
```

Had to use z instead of * because of expansion

Comment: looks its not the right tool :P

Comment: You can save a couple of characters by not quoting `tr`'s parameters when they contain nothing expandable.

Comment: In regards to your other bash answer: Feel free to fix, and then flag for mod attention requesting undeletion.

Comment: Looking again, there are quite many rexes for a `r=REXrex` variable to worth.

Comment: If you keep $r out of quoted string, you not need to change the surrounding `'` to `"`, so no need to escape the literal `"`. Of course, then you write a literal newline by breaking the line in that place instead of `\n`:  `$r'",. !␤'`.

Comment: :) I wonder if I can change echo and for with tr to have tr only answer

Answer (score 2):

### C#, <s>93</s> 90 bytes

```
s=>System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(s,"(?i)rex|\w",m=>m.Length>1?m.Value:"*");
```

Believe this is the first time I've used a regex in a C# answer here because of the long namespace `System.Text.RegularExpressions`.

---

Didn't realise it when I wrote my answer but this seems to be the C# version of [@Shaggy's JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119742/38550).

Comment: Thanks for the mention, even though you came up with your answer independently of mine.

Comment: @Shaggy Ah thanks didn't know it had been updated

Answer (score 2):

## Perl, 31 bytes

```
s/(rex)|[a-z]/$1||"*"/ieg;print
```

Invoke perl with `-n` option. For example:

```
echo 'To call rex, just say "Rex".'| perl -ne 's/(rex)|[a-z]/$1||"*"/ieg;print'
** **** rex, **** *** "Rex".
```

Comment: `[a-z]` can now be replaced with `\w` as the input will never contain numbers or underscores.

Comment: You can use `-p` instead of `-n` and remove `;print`

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 39 bytes

```
q{_3<_el"rex"=3{elc_'{,97>&'*@?1}?\o>}h
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@19YHW9sE5@ao1SUWqFka1ydmpMcr16tY2lup6au5WBvWGsfk29Xm/H/f1BqhY6Cp0JJfk6KQmV@qUJefgmQo5CSr1CSkVmsqBCZX6pelKqQm5idmZeukJuqkJiXXlSpANSmCAA)

**How it works**

```
q           e# Read the input.
{           e# Do:
 _3<        e#  Copy the string and get its first three characters.
 _el"rex"=  e#  Check case-insensitively if they equal "rex".
  3         e#   If they do, push 3.
  {         e#   If they don't:
   elc_     e#    Take the first character of the three, and make it lowercase.
   '{,97>&  e#    Take its set intersection with the lowercase alphabet. Returns a non-empty
            e#      string (truthy) if it's a letter or an empty string (falsy) if not.
   '*@?     e#    Push a * if the char is a letter, or itself if it's not.
   1        e#    Push 1.
  }?        e#  (end if)
 \o         e#  Print the second-from-the-top stack item.
 >          e#  Slice the string after the first 3 or 1 characters, depending on previous outcome.
}h          e# Repeat the above until the string is empty.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>96</s> <s>98</s> <s>97</s> 96 bytes

+2 bytes for missing e's preceded by r or followed by x but not both

-1 byte for changing `[a-z&&[^rex]]` to `(?![rex])\\w`

```java
String a(String s){return s.replaceAll("(?i)r(?!ex)|(?<!r)e|e(?!x)|(?<!re)x|(?![rex])\\w","*");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#hY8xbsMwDEXn9BS0JqkIfIG0MHqALEm3OAOrEIYKWTZEOrHR@Owuk6ZrO5Gf5Pvg9xGZYYshwdfTqh8@YvDAgqLl3IUTtLqye8khNYcjYG7Y6eHqTrSvkOhyp63b6HQ/sVBbdoOUvRISk21LtGZHI8RwJgalVERMp9K4P5n3DjzGeDtfw@fAAowT1Dev2vwHbyeFBQJDQyL6O2DqMo3BP8h5@ckE@AgHmiuTDDkBl5n6iJ7eYrTGVsFlWxU0uqutXors6EqqfyW5UZvioO5HV9cXszbPxm3mZV6@AQ)

A regex version for replacing using Java

Replaces everything in this regex with a * (note in Java \w has to be escaped as \\w)

```java
(?i)r(?!ex)|(?<!r)e|e(?!x)|(?<!re)x|(?![rex])\w

(?i)                                                   // Case Insensitive
    r(?!ex)                                            // Any r not followed by ex
           |(?<!r)e                                    // Or any e not preceded by r
                   |e(?!x)                             // Or any e not followed by x
                          |(?<!re)x                    // Or any x not preceded by re
                                   |(?![rex])\w        // Or any other word character
```

Answer (score 1):

## VimScript, 34 bytes

```
s/\v(rex|r@<=ex|(re)@<=x)@!\w/*/gi
```

And here's an interesting substitution that almost works:

```
s/\vr(ex)@!|<e|<x|[rex]@!\w/*/gi
```

Imagine running this repeatedly on the string `Rex, dex, I told you not to do this! You're making me angry Rex!` After the first line, the string is `Rex, *ex, * **** *** *** ** ** ****! ***'*e ****** *e ***** Rex!` The second pass will result in `Rex, **x, * **** *** *** ** ** ****! ***'** ****** ** ***** Rex!`, and the third pass will finish it. Any subsequent passes will not change the string. However, it could take more than 3 substitutions to get there, for example on string `xxxxxxxx`. So, if there were an easy way to run the above substitution until it stopped changing things, or as many times as the length of the input, that would be another solution. I bet it could be done in V, but it would still probably be longer than 34 bytes.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Here's [a V answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152536/31716). :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/CodePage)

*No response in over 24 hours to [my question regarding case](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119718/what-my-dog-really-hears?answertab=votes#comment293505_119718), so I'll post this tentative 23 byter.*

```
“rex”
Œlœṣ¢µØaW;”*yµ€j¢
```

See the test cases at **[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYU5RasWjhrlcRyflHJ38cOfiQ4sObT08IzHcGiioVXlo66OmNVmHFv0/uudwO5AZCeI@atz@cMeSQ0v@/49WD0qtUMjJLEstVsjMUwBychLzUvTUdRTUQ/IVkhNzckBiOgpZpcUlCsWJlQpKQK4SWN63EihfopBZrJCeWlKSmZeukJiXD3RLZrKeeiwA)**

#### How?

```
“rex” - Link 1, get "rex": no arguments
“rex” - literal "rex"

Œlœṣ¢µØaW;”*yµ€j¢ - Main link: string s (or list of characters)
Œl                - convert s to lowercase
    ¢             - call the last link (1) as a nilad (get "rex")
  œṣ              - split left (s) at sublists equal to right ("rex")
     µ            - call the result t
             µ€   - for each word, w, in t:
      Øa          -   literal: lowercase alphabet
        W         -   wrap it in a list
          ”*      -   literal: '*'
         ;        -   concatenate the wrapped alphabet with the asterisk
            y     -   translate: replace all lowercase letters with asterisks.
                ¢ - call the last link (1) as a nilad (get "rex")
               j  - join left (translated, split text) with copies of right ("rex")
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is valid. It doesn't match the test cases.

Comment: See my note right at the top, and my question to OP.

Comment: ( although unfortunately the comment I linked to where the OP said "dogs don't get the difference between lowercase and uppercase" has now gone)

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 26 bytes (uppercase output) / 36 bytes (case-preserving)

```
qeu"REX":R/{__el-'*@?}f%R*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@YWqoU5BqhZBWkXx0fn5qjq67lYF@bphqk9f9/UGqFjoKnQkl@TopCZX6pQl5@CZCjkJKvUJKRWayoEJlfql6UqpCbmJ2Zl66Qm6qQmJdeVKkA1KYIAA)

If letter case needs to be preserved (since [that's still a little bit unclear](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119718/what-my-dog-really-hears#comment293505_119718)), that can be accomplished with 10 extra bytes:

```
q_32f&:i\eu"REX":R/{__el-'*@?}f%R*.|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@18Yb2yUpmaVGZNaqhTkGqFkFaRfHR@fmqOrruVgX5umGqSlV/P/f1BqhY6Cp0JJfk6KQmV@qUJefgmQo5CSr1CSkVmsqBCZX6pelKqQm5idmZeukJuqkJiXXlSpANSmCAA)

By the way, while writing this answer, I found what I would consider to be a design bug in CJam: the bitwise operators `&` and `|` are not defined between two char values, so I can't use `.|` to take the bitwise OR of two strings.  The solution, which ended up costing me two extra bytes, is to first convert one of the strings with `:i` into an array of integers, which then can be ORed with the other string.  (Actually it cost me *three* bytes, because if `&` worked between two chars, I could've also used `Sf&` instead of `32f&` to save the letter case information.)

On the positive side, I did discover that `{...}f%` indeed works as expected for iterating over the characters in an array of strings.  Nice.

Anyway, here's a (lightly) commented version of the 36-byte code:

```
q                                       "read input";
 _32f&:i\                               "save the case bit of each input char";
         eu"REX":R/                     "uppercase input and split it on 'REX'";
                   {                    "start code block:"
                    __el-'*@?           "c = (c != lowercase(c) ? '*' : c)";
                             }f%        "apply block to chars in each substring";
                                R*      "join the substrings with 'REX' again";
                                  .|    "bitwise OR the case bits back in";
```

The case-saving trick works because the case of ASCII letters is solely determined by the fifth bit of the ASCII code: this bit is 0 for uppercase and 1 for lowercase letters.  Thus, taking the bitwise AND of the character code with 32 = 2<sup>5</sup> extracts the case bit, and bitwise ORing this bit with the uppercased letters restores their original case.

Of course, non-alphabetic characters may have arbitrary values for the fifth bit (although, due to the way ASCII characters are organized, most punctuation characters have the fifth bit set to 1) but this doesn't matter, since those characters are left untouched by uppercasing and the letter censoring loop anyway, and ORing a character with its own fifth bit does't change it.  Also, conveniently, the `*` character already has the fifth bit set, so it is also left unchanged by the final `.|`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

A port of my [JavaScript solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119742/58974), with a little help from [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/Oliver). Would be 16 in Japt v2 but RegEx is very bugged right now.

```
r`(x)|%l`Ïª'*}'i
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=cmAonHgpfCVsYM%2bqJyp9J2k&input=IlJleCwgSSB0b2xkIHlvdSBub3QgdG8gZG8gdGhpcyEgWW91J3JlIG1ha2luZyBtZSBhbmdyeSBSZXghIg)

### [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

If, as some other solutions assume, output case is irrelevant.

```
v Ër\l'*}`x
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=diDLclxsJyp9YJx4&input=IlJleCwgSSB0b2xkIHlvdSBub3QgdG8gZG8gdGhpcyEgWW91J3JlIG1ha2luZyBtZSBhbmdyeSBSZXghIg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
qR-`(rex)|\w`{b|'*}
```

Takes input from stdin, outputs to stdout. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P@/MEg3QaMotUKzJqY8oTqpRl2r9v//oNQKhZzMstRihcw8BSAnJzEvRe8/AA)

#### Explanation

```
q                    Read a line of stdin
 R                   and replace
   `(rex)|\w`          a regex matching `rex` or any single alphanumeric character,
  -                    case-insensitive
             {    }  with this callback function:
              b|'*     If the 1st capture group (rex) matched, return it, else asterisk
                       The result of the replacement is auto-printed
```

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 147 bytes

```
	L =INPUT
	K =ANY(&UCASE &LCASE)
B	L ARB . X (('R' | 'r') 'ex') . Y REM . L	:F(O)
R	X K ='*'	:S(R)
	O =O X Y :(B)
O	L K ='*'	:S(O)
	OUTPUT =O L
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY6xDoIwGITn9inOhb81hsmJhAEQE2OlpkACIyCDiYFEFzS@e/2ZXO6G@@5yr2nu58fee2EQn4prXUlxRpwUrQrqLClzBGY1LVMmEpciRAOlyBG@oCdp0Liwhmjh8gu7EdFRWS2daMBTtCURlcppKSxiy@0WkUq1tDz4z@2a1xUfWCEj8@LgfdcPNyzv3QfdNLtxuQ8b@QM)

Previous version did not properly handle non-alphabetic characters.

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), <s>27</s>, 24 bytes

I'm leaving both answers up, because I think they're equally interesting.

## 27 bytes

```
òÓãr¨ex©À!ü¼eü¼xü[rex]À!÷/*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///Cmw5MPLy46tCK14tDKww2Kh/cc2pMKIioO74kuSq2IBYlt19f6/z8otUJHIQVEeCqU5OekKFTmlyrk5ZcAOQop@QolGZnFigqR@aXqRakKuYnZmXnpCrmpCol56UWVCkC9igA)

Thanks to Brian McCutchon for his idea to [do this in V](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119887/31716)

Hexdump:

```
00000000: f2d3 e372 a865 78a9 c021 fcbc 65fc bc78  ...r.ex..!..e..x
00000010: fc5b 7265 785d c021 f72f 2a              .[rex].!./*
```

Explanation:

```
ò                           " Until the output stops changing...
 Óãr¨ex©À!ü¼eü¼xü[rex]À!÷/* " Run the compressed vim regex:

:s/\vr(ex)@!|<e|<x|[rex]@!\w/*/gi
```

## 24 bytes

```
Óãrex/ò&ò
HòÓ÷/*/e
jjòÍî
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///Dkw4uLUiv0D29SO7yJy@PwJqDAdn0t/VSurCwgp/fwuv//g1IrdBRSQISnQkl@TopCZX6pQl5@CZCjkJKvUJKRWayoEJlfql6UqpCbmJ2Zl66Qm6qQmJdeVKkA1KsIAA)

```
Ó           " Substitute
 ã          "   (case-insensitive)
  rex       "   'rex'
     /      " with
       &    "   'rex'
      ò ò   "   Surrounded in new lines
ò           " Recursively...
 Ó          "   Substitute...
  ÷         "     A word character
   /        "   with
    *       "     An asterisk
     /e     "     (don't break if there are 0 matches)
jj          "   Move down 2 lines
  ò         " end the recursive loop
   Íî       " Remove all newlines
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
l…rex©₄ç:AS'*:₄ç®:s.Ï
```

I've assumed the input can contain any ASCII character and only upper and lowercase letters are replaced with asterisks. It could be 2 bytes less if we assume the input will never contain substring `1000`, in which case both `ç` can be removed.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##HY0xDoJAFER7TjFuQ2J0D0BjLEi0sEEK2hV/YM1mSfiLgc4Ye2@hsfEQcBMugovFT@bPTOZVrE6apsmMt1dNbf8Z74/hHW2P4TL6y/4bsRye0ySESKiF0VdiaAv/GGXPMkgr5MqY2Vjh0rADqw5zWcjg0PnQQTMKck7bAspWHqRzGezImGqFJM4W2LMNHVzpi1JKKFidE/LSD5MtaBPM7DrO/LWelCHtar/EqqkbXs8sIX4)

**Explanation:**

```python
l           # Convert the (implicit) input to lowercase
 …rex       # Push string "rex"
     ©      # Store it in the register (without popping)
      ₄ç    # Push 1000 and convert it to a character: "Ϩ"
        :   # Replace all "rex" with "Ϩ"
AS          # Push the lowercase alphabet, and convert it to a list of characters
  '*       '# Push "*"
    :       # Replace every letter in the alphabet with "*"
₄ç          # Push "Ϩ" again
  ®         # Push "rex" from the register
   :        # Replace all "Ϩ" with "rex"
s           # Swap to take the (implicit) input again at the top of the stack
 .Ï         # Match the case of the lowercase "rex" with that of the input
            # (and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [PegJS](https://pegjs.org/) + ES6, 50 bytes

```
C=a:("rex"i/[a-z]i{return'*'}/.)*{return a.join``}
```

[Online interpreter](https://pegjs.org/online)

The lack of lambda syntax for the expression returns hurts the size.

Comment: `[a-z]` can now be replaced with `\w` as the input will never contain numbers or underscores.

Comment: PegJS is an implementation of Parsing Expression Grammar.  While the overall grammar can accept many more things than regular expressions, the individual `[a-z]` construct is not a regular expression; it is only a simple character class matcher and doesn't have `\w` or any equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

## Julia, <s>69</s> 50 bytes.

```
f(x)=replace(x,r"rex|[a-z]"i,a->length(a)>1?a:"*")
```

Took some ideas from more concise entries, now it works like them.

Comment: `[a-z]` can now be replaced with `\w` as the input will never contain numbers or underscores.

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) 2.0a0, 17 bytes

```
r/(Rex)|\l/i@Yª'*
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ci8oUmV4KXxcbC9pQFmqJyo=&input=LW1SIFsKIlJleCwgSSB0b2xkIHlvdSBub3QgdG8gZG8gdGhpcyEgWW91J3JlIG1ha2luZyBtZSBhbmdyeSBSZXghIiwKJ1JleCBsaXZlcyBpbiBSZXhsYW5kLicsCidUbyBjYWxsIFJleCwganVzdCBzYXkgIlJleCIuJywKJ015IGNhdCBpcyBnZXR0aW5nIGFub3JleGljLicsCiJIZWxsbyEgSXNuJ3QgdGhpcyAuLi4gYSBuaWNlIGNoYWxsZW5nZT8iCl0=)

#### Unpacked & How it works

```
Ur/(Rex)|\l/iXYZ{Y||'*

Ur  Replace on input...
/(Rex)|\l/i  Match this regex globally...
             (`\l` stands for [A-Za-z], and Japt regexes have `g` by default)
XYZ{Y||'*    and replace anything that isn't Rex into '*'.
```

`S.r` uses JS's `String.replace` which can accept a function as 2nd input, but unfortunately, the Japt doc doesn't mention it.

Idea adapted from [Martin Ender's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119734/78410).

Answer (score 0):

## [K4](https://kx.com/download), 56 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{@[;r;:;x@r:,/ss[_x;"rex"]+\:!3]@[x;&(_x)in .Q.a;:;"*"]}
```

**Examples:**

```
q)k){@[;r;:;x@r:,/ss[_x;"rex"]+\:!3]@[x;&(_x)in .Q.a;:;"*"]}"Rex lives in Rexland."
"Rex ***** ** Rex****."
q)k){@[;r;:;x@r:,/ss[_x;"rex"]+\:!3]@[x;&(_x)in .Q.a;:;"*"]}"To call Rex, just say \"Rex\"."
"** **** Rex, **** *** \"Rex\"."
q)k){@[;r;:;x@r:,/ss[_x;"rex"]+\:!3]@[x;&(_x)in .Q.a;:;"*"]}"My cat is getting anorexic."
"** *** ** ******* ***rex**."
```

**Explanation:**

No regular expressions here... Change everything non-alphabetic into stars, put back any occurences of Rex:

```
{@[;r;:;x@r:,/ss[_x;"rex"]+\:!3]@[x;&(_x)in .Q.a;:;"*"]} / the solution
{                                                      } / lambda taking implicit x
                                @[x;            ;:;"*"]  / apply (@) assignment (:) of "*" at indices...
                                         in .Q.a         / in lowercase alphabet?
                                     (_x)                / lowercase (_) x       
                                    &                    / indices where true                                  
 @[; ;:;                       ]                         / another application of assignment
                             !3                          / range til 3 -> 0 1 2
                          +\:                            / add (+) to each left (\:)
              ss[_x;"rex"]                               / string-search for "rex" in lowercase (_) x
            ,/                                           / flatten
          r:                                             / assign to r
        x@                                               / index into x
    r                                                    / indices to modify
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 99 bytes

```
f(s)=>s.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(rex)|(\w)',caseSensitive:false),(Match m)=>m[1]!=null?m[1]:'*');
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BasMwDIbveQqtF9sjBHZtyMoOPebS7db1IBwl9XAcYytdStdnz1QGu4jvlz5@1GHide11Ns1rrhJFj5bevG8xRur0gYb9EnVSOtFifvTnt1GlxUzvFLJjd6Ftjz6TKXWLbM8wSs94fDk9NWH2fvfArXpWpl5HdEGbWwFwwQTcHIUA1IEW8NKTwQWQ4DF0lSr/jh8TWPT@sS/ha84MGa@wkbj5d9qrOAwuw0DMLgyAYZJvna2UGKe6kMlVP6U92rPWs7nF5ALrXtDUd1MX9/UX)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ùV:┬KsS•u┤8α╞"T-┤☼
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=97563ac24b73530775b438e0c622542db40f&i=%22Rex+lives+in+Rexland.%22%0A%22To+call+Rex,+just+say+%5C%22Rex%5C%22.%22%0A%22My+cat+is+getting+anorexic.%22%0A&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score -1):

## JS (ES5), 75 bytes

```
function r(l){return l.replace(/rex|\w/gi,function(c){return c[1]?c:"*"})}
```

Based on [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119789/58974)

Comment: Is "porting" an answer to another version of the same language permitted? I don't know. But you should at least include a credit in your answer by linking to the original as TheLethalCoder did (unnecessarily, in that case) in [their answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119789/58974).

Comment: You may replace `[a-z]` with `\w`.